# Probability of a random variable less than the other

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, proof-verification

Suppose X and Y are jointly distributed random variables with joint pdf as $$f(x,y)= abe^{ax+by}$$
$-\infty<x,y <0$
Then what is the $$P(X<Y)=? $$
I first calculated thru a tranformation $X=U+V$ and $Y=V$
and calculated the joint pdf of U and V and then integrated on V between the limits $-\infty$ to $0$ when $-\infty<u<0$
And between $-\infty$ to $-u$ when u is between 0 and $\infty $
Afer this i calculated the $P(U<0)$
Is this correct because i got the answer as $$ b/(a+b)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is so.  Although your method is a little roundabout.

$\begin{align}\mathsf P(X<Y) = & ~ \int_{-\infty}^0\int_{-\infty}^y ab\mathsf e ^{ax+by}\operatorname d x\operatorname d y\\[1ex] = & ~ \int_{-\infty}^0 b\mathsf e^{(a+b)y}\operatorname d y\\[1ex] = & ~ {\frac{b}{a+b}}\end{align}$

Comment: Thnx..but i see that my approach isn't right is it??

Comment: It's not *wrong* per se.  It worked.  The change of variables was just more effort than was strictly necessary.  @user312254